# Mongo - Replace references with embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Collection with a nested attribute that is an array of ObjectId References. These refer to documents in another Collection.

I'd like to replace these references with the documents themselves, i.e. embed those documents where the references are now. I've tried with and without the .snapshot() option. This may be caused because I'm updating a document while in a loop on that doc, and .snapshot() isn't available at that level.

My mongo-fu is low and I'm stuck on a call stack error. How can I do this?

Example code:

```js
db.CollWithReferences.find({}).snapshot().forEach( function(document) {
    var doc_id = document._id;
    document.GroupsOfStuff.forEach( function(Group) {    
        var docsToEmbed= db.CollOfThingsToEmbed.find({ _id: { $in: Group.ArrayOfReferenceObjectIds }});

        db.CollWithReferences.update({"_id": ObjectId(doc_id) },
            {$set: {"Group.ArrayOfReferenceObjectIds ":docsToEmbed}} )
    });
});
```

Gives this error:

```js
{
    "message" : "Maximum call stack size exceeded",
    "stack" : "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" +
    ....}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure this is happening for one of two reasons. Either you are running out of memory by executing two queries in a for loop, or the update operation is being executed before the find operation has finished.

Either way, it is not a good idea to execute too many queries in a for loop as it can lead to this type of error.

I can't be sure if this will fix your problem as I don't know how many documents are in your collections, but it may work if you first get all documents from the `CollWithReferences` collection, then all you need from the `CollOfThingsToEmbed` collection. Then build a map of an `_id` from the `CollOfThingsToEmbed` collection to the actual document that corresponds to that. You can then loop through each document you got from the `CollWithReferences` collection, and mutate the `groupsOfStuff` array by accessing each `ArrayOfReferenceObjectIds` array and setting the ObjectId to the value that you have in the map you already built up, which will be the whole document. Then just update that document by setting `GroupsOfSuff` to its mutated value.

The following JavaScript code will do this (it could be organised better to have no logic in the global scope etc.):

```
var references = db.CollWithReferences.find({});


function getReferenceIds(references) {
    var referenceIds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < references.length; i++) {
        var group = references[i].GroupsOfStuff;
        for (let j = 0; j < group.ArrayOfReferenceObjectIds; j++) {
            referenceIds.push(group.ArrayOfReferenceObjectIds[j]);
        }
    }

    return referenceIds;
}


function buildIdMap(docs) {
    var map = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        map[docs[i]._id.toString()] = docs[i];
    }

    return map;
}

var referenceIds = getReferenceIds(references);
var docsToEmbed = db.CollOfThingsToEmbed.find({_id: {$in: referenceIds}});


var idMap = buildIdMap(docsToEmbed);

for (var i = 0; i < references.length; i++) {
    var groups = references[i].GroupsOfStuff;
    for (var j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {
        refs = groups[j].ArrayOfReferenceObjectIds;

        refs.forEach(function(ref) {
            ref = idMap[ref.toString()];
        });
    }

    db.CollWithReferences.update({
        _id: ObjectId(ref._id)
    }, {
        $set: {GroupsOfStuff: groups}
    });
}
```

It would be better if it was possible to just do one bulk update, but as each document needs to be updated differently, this is not possible.